# Passing String in HashMap to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-listview, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` where I have parsed some JSON data. The map has some String values which are Urls. I am showing the Map values into a `ListView`. I want to open the Url associated with that particular list entry into another activity that holds a `WebView`.
But I get a `NullPointerException` when I try to pass the values between the activities.

Here is my code:-

MainActivity.java

```
     map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                                map.put(SOURCETITLE, title);
                                map.put(TITLE, description);
                                map.put(THUMBNAILPATH, thumbnail);

                                myNewsList.add(map);


                        }
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                        itemsAdapter = new LazyAdapter(this, myList);
                        newsList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
                        newsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                    View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                                 Intent nIntent = new Intent(Home.this,DetailedInfo.class);
                                nIntent.putExtra("Items", myList);
                                startActivity(nIntent);
                            }
                        });
```

DetailedInfo.Java

```
Intent in = getIntent();

    data =  (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) in.getSerializableExtra("Items");
    for(int pos=0;pos<data.size();pos++)
    {
    HashMap<String, String> urls = data.get(pos);
    String newUrl = urls.get(Home.URL);
    }
    myNews = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webNewsDetails);
    myNews.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myNews.loadUrl(newUrl);
    myNews.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

you put the HashMap with key `"Items"` and try to retrieve with key `"NewsItems"`. You should use the same key to put and retrieve the element.

Edit:

you are casting to the wrong object. You pass an instance of a `HashMap<String, String>` and cast it to `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`

Comment: `myList` is a ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Comment: could you at least tell where do you get the exception? Is it still a NPE?

Comment: I get the exception on the ` myNews.loadUrl(newUrl);`

Comment: I see, but myList is empty. Can you post the actual code that it's causing the crash?